# 2D Array, output is no where near correct

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;
        String arrayLine = "";
        int counter = 0;

        rows = sc.nextInt();
        cols = sc.nextInt();
        arrayLine = sc.next();

        char[][] array = new char[rows][cols];

        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            for (int c=0; c<cols; c++){
                array[r][c] = arrayLine.charAt(counter);
                counter ++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

The document I'm bringing in the information from is:

```
8
7
000000011111S0000000110101111010101100010110111011010E00
```

---

The output I'm getting it when i run it is `[[C@252f0999`

Help please, I'm just starting to learn java!

Answer (score 5):

`array` is a special kind of object, it doesn't have an implicit `toString()` which manages pretty printing of the content of the array, what happens is that the object is represented by the standard representation for objects which is its hashcode.

You should use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
```

Mind that you can't directly write `Arrays.toString(array)` because, as stated in documentation:

> If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

Answer (score 4):

When you call println() on an object, Java returns the location of the resource by default (that's what C@252.... is). You want to call

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array)
```

to display the data in the array.